# How to write create table statement in stored procedure

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures

How to write the below query in stored proc in postgresql?

```
 create table data1 as
 select A.*,
 case when score >=940 then 1
 when score between 600 and 746 then 2
 when bureau_score between 599 and 630 then 4 else 5 end as score_level,
 case when band between -1 and 5 then 1
 when band between 6 and 20 then 2
 when band between 21 and 35 then 3 else 4 end as band_level
 from data A;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Postgresql doen't have stored procedures as such, only functions, so.

If it's simple SQL you can simply wrap in in an SQL function definition.

```
create or replace function foo () returns void language sql as $$

  create table data1 as
  select A.*,
  case when score >=940 then 1
  when score between 600 and 746 then 2
  when bureau_score between 599 and 630 then 4 else 5 end as score_level,
  case when band between -1 and 5 then 1
  when band between 6 and 20 then 2
  when band between 21 and 35 then 3 else 4 end as band_level
  from data A;

$$;
```

To call it do `SELECT foo();`